# How to handle postMessage Error: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow'?

Tags: angular, iframe, postmessage

I'm facing an issue when trying to have my page available on an iFrame, when it is included in another one as an iFrame, i get the message:

'Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://undefined') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://parent.com.br').'

the origins are indeed different, **however differently from other posts**, **mine is getting 'undefined' at the message.**

The iFrame is as follows:

```
<iframe src="https://mypage/details" 
            sandbox=" allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-presentation allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-forms allow-modals 
allow-pointer-lock allow-popups  allow-scripts allow-top-navigation" height="646px" width="100%">
</iframe>
```

Is there anything I should do in my page, in order to be possible to put it on the iFrame?

My page is provided by angular-8 application.

Thanks